# How to stop unwanted message?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, indexing

My code keeps displaying an unwanted message:

```
#Initializes variable to search array and gets user input
search = str(input('What is a dealer name?'))
#loop to perform search
for index in range(0,array):
#Outputs for search, depending on conditions 
    if (name[index]) == search:
        print(sales[index])
        print(comm[index])
    else:  
        print('Error')
```

The goal is to search for a name, then display the sales and commissions for that name. If there's no name, it should display, "Error."

Yet, this is the result:

```
What is a dealer name?j
1
0.05
Error
```

Why does error keep appearing?

Comment: What is `array`?  What is `name`?  What is `sales`?  What is `comm`?

Comment: Probably because you have a loop, and the first time through `name[index] == search` and the second time not

Answer (score 0):

*For each element* in the loop, you are looking to see if that element matches and if not, you print `Error`.  Instead, you want to print `Error` if *no matches are found* after all iterations of the loop.

It might be better to find the index in the array using the `.index` method of lists.  It will raise a `ValueError` if the thing you are searching for isn't present, so you need to handle that as well:

```
try:
    idx = name.index(search)
    print(sales[idx])
    print(comm[idx])
except ValueError:
    print('Error')
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you will only ever find one result, in that case you can use the else clause of for:

```
#Initializes variable to search array and gets user input
search = str(input('What is a dealer name?'))
#loop to perform search
for index in range(0,array):
#Outputs for search, depending on conditions 
    if (name[index]) == search:
        print(sales[index])
        print(comm[index])
        break
else:  
    print('Error')
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to search array, it will be slow. Best will be use dictionary. Since, you don't have to iterate it, it's faster to search.

```
#Initializes variable to search array and gets user input

dealerSales = {}
dealerComm = {}

dealerSales["DAVID"] = 50
dealerComm["DAVID"] = 0.05

dealerSales["GON"] = 100
dealerComm["GON"] = 0.01

search = raw_input('What is a dealer name?').strip()

if search in dealerSales:
    print dealerSales[search]
    print dealerComm[search]
else:
    print "Error"
```

Output

```
What is a dealer name? GON
100
0.01

What is a dealer name? DAVID
50
0.05

What is a dealer name? JOHN
Error
```